# Calling webservice from windows service

Tags: asp.net

I have a windows service project that references an asp.net webservice.  When I run this service locally on my machine via VS it works fine and when I call the web method I get the results I want.

Today I deployed this to a test server and when I call the web method it fails because the it is trying to connect to the local host webservice and not the one on the server.  The error I get is "Unable to Connect to remote server -->  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it: 127.0.0.1"

My service has a app.config file and the web service settings are correctly pointing at the webservice url.  I know the url is correct as when I put it into IE it resolves to the webservice.  Also the properties of the webservices are correct.

Any suggestions on how the service is getting hold of localhost would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: write a log entry printing the service URL after you initialize the proxy. I am guessing there is an issue with the config, but can't point without seeing the code. If possible, post the service calling code and config

Comment: Could be a windows security issue. Are you calling the process/web method as an elevated? Also, is Windows Firewall Service Running? If so is there an exception for the IP/port/app process? Is RPC running? Check credentials and those listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this today at work with the following lines of code.

```
webservice ws = new webservice()   
ws.Url = (new xxxx.Properties.Settings()).WS;
ws.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Thanks for all your help guys
Cheers
APW

Answer (score 0):

Could be a windows security issue. Are you calling the process/web method as an elevated? Also, is Windows Firewall Service Running? If so is there an exception for the IP/port/app process? Is RPC running? Check credentials and those listed above.

Comment: @APW, you missed the code :) please edit your question to insert code snippet

Comment: The code in the windows service calling the webservice is like the below:
    webservice ws = new webservice()                                     
ws.callMethod()  // this is where it falls over

Config:
<application settings>
<Service.Properties.Settings>
<setting name="Web Service name" serializeAS="String"> 
<value> url of webservices</value>
</settings>       
</applicationSettings>

Comment: sorry note worked out how to format this yet.  The config file was autogenerated by VS.  Above is just a snippet I have retyped as I am on a different computer now

Comment: at some point it's looping back. Do you have localhost, or the current machine name referenced somewhere?

Comment: I have searched the project for local host as well as the server for files that may contain local host and I can't find any refrences to it???

Comment: @AmitApollo. The proxy object's url has never been set to remote server in APW's code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you store your proxy's address using the standard WCF configuration. Here's an example.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://yourServerIP:51717/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```